# Divide oranges into different sized boxes. Java Puzzle

Tags: java, methods

Theres three boxes

User inputs the number of oranges.

Large box holds 20, medium 10 and the small 5 oranges.

The shipping cost of a large box is $8.80, medium box, $6.00 and small box $4.50.

The order is shipped in the least expensive manner.

For example, the order of 52 oranges will be shipped in four boxes: two large, one medium, and one small.

This is where it gets tricky.

The rule for packing is to fill the large and medium boxes completely; that is, the box is fully packed.

Only the small boxes can have empty spaces. For example, to ship 52 oranges, you could have used 3 large boxes, but that would leave the third box not fully packed.

Shipping cost should be displayed and method should be used in java

Anyone care to help an old guy learning java out?

Comment: Hmm i tried using modulus and divide but couldn't calculate shipping correctly, answer was incorrect.

Comment: Possibly you can post your code so that we can find where the problem is.

Comment: i haven't written much down to be honest, i just began and was puzzled by this, apparently it supposed to be very easy but i can't figure out the equation that will be used

Answer (score 1):

I will not provide a solution for you, as you wanted help to **learn** and not to *solve*:

> Anyone care to help an old guy learning java out?

I suggest to do the following:

1. Define an algorithm, that will generate all possible shipping methods
2. Optional: Define a "filter" that will automatically skip obviously bad shipping methods
3. Go through the shipping methods, find the cheapest one.

I recommend to use Java-8-streaming - it can make your algorithms short and readable

Optional next step:

4. rewrite your code to create the shipping methods as a "tree" - so you can skip whole branches that are obviously more expensive than other branches

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a modulus will tell you if the number of oranges you have, fit in a box (the box is full for medium and big boxes), if yes, try again with the remaining oranges, it no try with a smaller box until you have no orange left.

This should be enough since there is no case where shipping two small boxes is cheaper than one big box.

EDIT: I've finally changed my mind and modulus is not needed. I've used an integer division to make it work.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int oranges = 15;

    int bigBoxes = oranges / 20;
    int mediumBoxes = (oranges-bigBoxes*20) / 10;
    int smallBoxes = ((oranges-bigBoxes*20-mediumBoxes*10)+4) / 5;

    System.out.println(String.format("big=%d, med=%d, small=%d", bigBoxes, mediumBoxes, smallBoxes));
}
```

Comment: Not modulus but the simple `>=` operator.

Comment: could you elaborate how >= would work exactly?

Comment: With 15 orange the only solution is to use a medium and a small box. I forgot to define fit in a box. Edited.

Comment: while( numberOranges >= bigBox){ bigBoxes++; numberOranges-=bigBox;}